# Mysql query performance with concurrent read,write

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench, query-performance

I have a simple table, with 15 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE(
ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
SYMBOL varchar(100) NOT NULL,
DATE varchar(100) NOT NULL,
TIME varchar(100) NOT NULL,
NUMBER decimal(38,0) NOT NULL,
A float DEFAULT NULL,
B float DEFAULT NULL,
C float DEFAULT NULL,
D float DEFAULT NULL,
E decimal(38,0) DEFAULT NULL,
F float DEFAULT NULL,
G decimal(38,0) DEFAULT NULL,
H decimal(38,0) DEFAULT NULL,
I decimal(38,0) DEFAULT NULL,
J float DEFAULT NULL,
K float DEFAULT NULL,
L decimal(38,0) DEFAULT NULL,
M decimal(38,0) DEFAULT NULL,
MILLIS decimal(38,0) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
KEY SYM (SYMBOL) USING HASH
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10250241 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

which is indexed by symbol(hash Index). There are around 10,000,000 rows in this table(6GB) of data. When I am querying this table in workbench, for a simple query like :

```
select  *  from MYTABLE WHERE symbol = 'A' and date>= '2018-08-01' and 
date<= '2018-08-09' and time>= '09:24:00' and time <= '15:24:00' order by 
millis desc ;'
```

it is taking 4-5 seconds. 
The performance further decreases when the reading and writing on the database happens together. But this is a real time database, it is a requirement that the data is written from one connection and read from another.

Can someone please suggest some ways to optimize performance. I already tried a BTREE index over time, but performance further reduced.

As suggested, after running an explain on my query, I got the following result:

```
'Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort'
```

[image: Explain result]

Comment: Run a `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` command, and post the results here please. You likely want an index covering multiple fields. In this case symbol and date. (Make sure it's ONE index, that has both fields, in that order)

Comment: I added the result of Explain. The number of dates I will have in my database will always be not more than 15-30. Should I still index them. Also I need my writing process to be fast (as it is real time, runs every minute on market data). Create another index might impact that.

Comment: Dump your original index, and replace it to include date, and then let me know of your updated results. While the index may get larger, doing lookups just on symbol should still use this index, and drastically speed up your read times on the query you're running.

Comment: What data does the MILLIS field contain? Is it a UTC timestamp of the corresponding "DATE" and "TIME" fields?

Comment: The query is taking 3.5 sec now, but my data loading process has become much slower. It was taking around 10 sec for a minutes data earlier and now it is taking 30+.

Answer (score 2):

```
DATE varchar(100) NOT NULL,
TIME varchar(100) NOT NULL,
```

I would start with using `DATE()` and `TIME()` types instead of `varchar` (or one `DATETIME()`) - or store them in `integer` as `Unix Time`. Internally they will be more efficient than strings.

For example, comparing two integers takes around 1 CPU cycle. To compare strings, in general, every character has to be compared in a loop (until there is a difference), unless special optimizations are used. In case the data were in unicode, special lookups would have to be made for each character.

Integers also take less space (4 bytes for Unix Time) than the date/time string representation, and are not variable in length (even if the dates are all the same length, internally they will be treated as variable length strings, requiring an extra 'length field').

Also create a proper index as suggested elsewhere.

```
select * from MYTABLE 
where symbol = 'A' and
      date >= '2018-08-01' and date <= '2018-08-09' and 
      time >= '09:24:00' and time <= '15:24:00'
order by millis desc ;
```

Are you sure you want to order (only) by `millis`, or is this just as a test?

For the above query, ignoring the separate sort on `millis`, ideally the records would be stored on disk in this order: `symbol, datetime (millis?)`. This way the records to be returned will be close together in blocks on disk. Otherwise they could be spread all over the table, requiring many disk seeks and (block)reads to retreive all the records.

Comment: Switching from comparing two char(100) fields to a single datetime will be a pretty huge improvement, but you have to realize that querying and updating 10M row table isn't going to be instant unless you have fast hardware behind it. You may want to see about getting a faster disk array and more ram.

Comment: @TerryCarmen Well, 10M records isn't that much. As for selecting the records: using a proper index this should be instant (a few ms max). As for retreiving the (full) records: it's all about how the data is organized on disk. For example 6GB / 10M = 600 bytes per record. If those records are contiguous on disk, only 600*527=316kB + some overhead would have to be read from disk, and even a cheap disk can read 100MB/s. If they are spread all over the table however, in the worst case up to 527 disk seeks @ 10ms each would have to be done ...

Comment: @TerryCarmen  ... And if less time is spent on querying the data and locks are freed more quickly, updating the data will also be faster (or at least will have more system time available).

Answer (score 0):

Create index on symbol and millis with desc.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
select * 
from MYTABLE 
where symbol = 'A' and
      date >= '2018-08-01' and date <= '2018-08-09' and 
      time >= '09:24:00' and time <= '15:24:00'
order by millis desc ;
```

You want an index on `mytable(symbol, date, time)`.  Actually `time` is only there as a copy so the index covers the `WHERE` clause.

Including `millis` is not helpful, because of the filtering needed before the `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

`DECIMAL(38,0)` takes 17 bytes.  Do you really need that datatype?  (`FLOAT` takes 4, `DOUBLE` takes 8, `BIGINT` takes 8.)  (Shrinking the 6GB will help performance some, especially if `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is small.)

If `millis` is for milliseconds, why is it 38 digits, not 3?  Anyway, `DATETIME(3)` provides a data + time + milliseconds all wrapped into about 7 bytes.  Furthermore, you can do

```
ORDER BY datetime
```

and thereby allow for the efficient `INDEX(symbol, datetime)` to help with the `WHERE`.  (This cannot be done with your current code.)

```
  date >= '2018-08-01' and date <= '2018-08-09' and 
  time >= '09:24:00' and time <= '15:24:00'
```

filters to daytime during each of those 9 days.  If that is really what you want, then no index will work well.  Check the use of `<=` -- I understand inclusitivity on the date, but I question it for the time.

Either `INDEX(symbol, date)` or `INDEX(symbol, time)` is useful.  Nothing else is better (unless you can combine date+time).  Add both of those.

`HASH` indexes do not exist in InnoDB; that request is silently turned into `BTREE`, which is about as good for 'point queries', and hugely better for 'range queries'.  In your query, a 'composite' BTree query (see previous paragraph) is much better.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` so we can further deduce what is going on.

Is everything other than `ID` really optional?  Consider using `NOT NULL`.

`'Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort'` -- "filesort" is unavoidable; live with it.  "Using index condition" (aka "ICP") is good.